# how to load some of the variables in a pickle file python? As in loading matlab files using scipy or hdf5storage

Tags: python, pickle

Let's say I have saved a pickle file with multiple variables:

```
import pickle

with open("file.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump((a,b,c,d,e,f), f)
```

The file can be loaded with:

```
with open("file.pickle", "rb") as f:
    a,b,c,d,e,f= pickle.load(f)
```

Is there a way to read just the first four variables other than saving the four variables in a separate file?

```
with open("file.pickle", "rb") as f:
    a,b,c,d=  ?? #load the first four variables only
```

Comment: IIRC, pickle can only save/load one variable at a time. You could store an array, and extract it as you are thinking of doing. But there's no way that I know of selectively loading one variable or more.

Comment: Is your goal only to *read* only some values (first n, last n, middle n, ...) or to *store* only some values (``a, b, c, d, *_ = pickle.load(f)``)? Do you want to do this without changing how the file is written in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't save 6 variables to a pickle file. That's not how pickles or variables work.

You constructed a 6-element tuple and wrote a pickle-format serialization of that tuple to a file. The pickle format does not support deserializing only parts of a serialized object; you have to load the whole tuple.

The pickle format is a sequence of instructions for building objects, and just like following half the recipe to bake a cake won't bake half a cake, you can't load half a pickle and get half the tuple you serialized.

Comment: As I recalled, got a bit unsure when users starts asking questions hehe. Good analogy btw, will use in the future hehe.

Comment: The pickle format can store three recipes to bake a cake and only read one recipe at a time, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: That's really 3 separate pickles written to the same file, but yeah, you can do that.

Comment: ohh, correct. I am just looking for a way to save multiple variables but reloading some of them. I cant use dill. Till this stage, the only way is to save each variable alone. Any other suggestion?